# Navigate a URL with Query string values on click of hyperlink

Tags: c#, query-string, navigateurl

I have a control with 'email' and 'password' textboxes and a 'autoLogin' checkbox. All are web form controls (not html controls). And there is a 'Login' hyperlink. When I click on heperlink, I want to move to other page using NavigateUrl property like below:

```
NavigateUrl="~/DoLogin.aspx?email={0}&pwd={1}&autoLogin={3}"
```

how to pass and how to get the query string?

Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Password in query string? Really?

Answer (score 3):

```
private void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
Response.Redirect("Webform2.aspx?Email=" +
this.txtemail.Text + "&Pwd=" +
txtPassword.Text);
}
```

now for the next page(Webform2.aspx) go there and in page load event write this code

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
string Email = Request.QueryString["Email"];
 string password = Request.QueryString["Pwd"];
}
```

You can use this one also

```
private void Page_Load(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
 string Email = Request.QueryString[0];
 string password = Request.QueryString[1];
}
```

place this values where You Want

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way would be to not use a hyperlink but a button (or link button) and make a postback and then use, `Response.Redirect("Url")` or event better, process the login directly. Otherwize you have to collect your data using javascript.

Answer (score 0):

On Login Click write this code

```
Response.Redirect("~/DoLogin.aspx?email=" + txtEmail.txt + "&pwd=" + txtPwd.text)
```

Comment: What if the password includes an ampersand? Server.UrlEncode() needs to be put around both strings. Although I would recommend doing this anyway for security reasons...

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your doing this because your DoLogin page has some login code in the `Page_Load`?

I really wouldn't recommend passing username/password credentials in a URL.

Like @Magnus has stated, it would be better to change the `Hyperlink` to a `LinkButton` and put your code in there.